# Basic Calculator in Java with Swing

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I used a standard calculator design from Java.  I wanted to expand it so I created a class to create buttons for different operations, like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. The original program didn't do this, they just made them individually without a template method.  Do you think I should do it like this?

```
//The java Template Calculator TODO

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Container;

public class JavaCalculator implements ActionListener{

JFrame guiFrame;
JPanel buttonPanel;
JTextField numberCalc;
int calcOperation = 0;
int currentCalc;

public static void main(String[] args) {

     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
     {

         public void run()
         {

             new JavaCalculator();         
         }
     });

}

public JavaCalculator()
{
    guiFrame = new JFrame();
    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    guiFrame.setTitle("Simple Calculator");
    guiFrame.setSize(300,300);
    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    numberCalc = new JTextField();
    numberCalc.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    numberCalc.setEditable(false);
    guiFrame.add(numberCalc, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));   
    guiFrame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        addNumberButton(buttonPanel, String.valueOf(i));
    }

    addActionButton(buttonPanel, 1, "+");
    addActionButton(buttonPanel, 2, "-");
    addActionButton(buttonPanel, 3, "*");
    addActionButton(buttonPanel, 4, "/");
    addActionButton(buttonPanel, 5, "^2");

    JButton equalsButton = new JButton("=");
    equalsButton.setActionCommand("=");
    equalsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if (!numberCalc.getText().isEmpty())
            {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(numberCalc.getText()); 
                if (calcOperation == 1)
                {
                    int calculate = currentCalc  + number;
                    numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                }
                else if (calcOperation == 2)
                {
                    int calculate = currentCalc  - number;
                    numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                }
                else if (calcOperation == 3)
                {
                    int calculate = currentCalc  * number;
                    numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                }
                else if (calcOperation == 4)
                {
                    int calculate = currentCalc  / number;
                    numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                }
                else if (calcOperation == 5)
                {
                    int calculate = currentCalc  * currentCalc;
                    numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    buttonPanel.add(equalsButton);
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);  
}

private void addNumberButton(Container parent, String name)
{
    JButton but = new JButton(name);
    but.setActionCommand(name);
    but.addActionListener(this);
    parent.add(but);
}

private void addActionButton(Container parent, int action, String text)
{
    JButton but = new JButton(text);
    but.setActionCommand(text);
    OperatorAction addAction = new OperatorAction(1);
    but.addActionListener(addAction);
    parent.add(but);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    String action = event.getActionCommand();

    numberCalc.setText(action);       
}

private class OperatorAction implements ActionListener
{
    private int operator;

    public OperatorAction(int operation)
    {
        operator = operation;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        currentCalc = Integer.parseInt(numberCalc.getText()); 
        calcOperation = operator;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

## Bug!

In your program, it's impossible to use any operator besides addition. As Code Review is not meant to be a code-bug-fixing site, I think you should try to fix this yourself. *Hint: The bug is in your `addActionButton` method*

### Now, about your question

Yes, the template method is a good choice. Removing code duplication is always a good idea, which is I have to inform you about some other improvements you can make as well.

#### Some things you should think about first

- Java coding convention is to put the `{` on the same line as before, not on it's own line.
- It is good practice to use `private final` on as many class-variables ("fields") as possible.
- It is an even better practice to reduce the scope of variables when possible, `buttonPanel` and `guiFrame` can be declared as local variables in the constructor.

#### Reducing duplication

- `numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));` is done on every if-case, put it after all the if-else statements instead.
- Instead of using several if-else, you can use a [`switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).
- An [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is a better choice than using an int to store the current calcOperation.

---

#### Java 8

If you are not allowed or unable to use Java 8, skip this section :)

If you can use Java 8, there's a way to do this very smoothly. It may be a bit advanced if you are new to the Java language, but if you are willing to learn I suggest you check out [IntBinaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html).

Your `int calcOperation` can be replaced with `IntBinaryOperator operator;`. Operations can be declared like this:

```
IntBinaryOperator add = (a, b) -> a + b;
IntBinaryOperator substract = (a, b) -> a - b;
IntBinaryOperator multiply = (a, b) -> a * b;
IntBinaryOperator divide = (a, b) -> a / b;
```

Your add action button can then become `private void addActionButton(Container parent, IntBinaryOperator action, String text) {`. This would **greatly** reduce code duplication for you, but as I said. This is only if you're using Java 8. If you're interested, add a comment and I'll explain more.

---

Regarding the user friendliness of your program, it's not layouted as a typical calculator. This is just a nitpick really. It would also be nice to use the keyboard for the program, but that's just a feature-request :)

Comment: I updated the code, I replaced the if else statements with switch, I created the JFrame guiFrame and JPanel buttonPanel within the class. I also fixed the bug, I already had it fixed in my compiler, it was probably an old version. { and } are now on the same line
    numberCalc.setText(Integer.toString(calculate));
now is outside the switch statement.

I don't know what you meant with enum, or how to do it.
My computer says it has Java 8 installed, but when I replace
    int calcOperation = 0;
with
    IntBinaryOperator operator;
it says it is an undefined variable.

Comment: I also replaced the for loop to generate numbers for the number buttons with simply: addNumberButton("number"); otherwise i wouldn't be able to put the number in a logical order, or would I?

Comment: @TheWombatGuru If you read the enum tutorial link in my post you should be able to use an enum. You can make one like `public enum Calculation { ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION; }` and then you can declare a `private Calculation activeCalculation;` which you can set to one of those values.

Comment: @TheWombatGuru For information on how to develop with Java 8, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Comment: @Simon_André_Forsberg, I made a class for the enum, but I don't know how to implement it into the calculator, I changed the cases in the switch statement to the capital words, but I don't know how I can give actions to the words.